# Свёртывание в Jar

Tags: java, jar

Написал приложение на Intellij IDEA. Сворачиваю в jar. Jar не открывается.
В приложении есть image с расширением png. Я получаю к ним доступ так и записываю их в массив image:

```
MIm[1][1] = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/Распределитель.png"));
```

Если убрать эти строки jar благополучно открывается. Так же если таких строк до 3х, он тоже открывается. Собственно не понимаю почему это происходит.
Я собираю jar через Open Module Setting - Artifacts и далее Build Artifacts
Если ли разница если собирать через Maven?

Comment: Покажи скрипт сборки и структуру проекта

Comment: _Не открывается_ очень содержательно звучит. Чем _не открывается_? Для чего его _открывать_? В какой момент _не открывается_? Переименуй расширение руками в *.zip и просмотри папку

Comment: @Tachkin Делаю приложение java на desktop. Не открывается по двойному щелчку. Не открывается когда добавлено более 3х строк описанных выше. В папку заглядывал там всё нормально.

Comment: @Темкатоже собираю в Intellij IDEA. Структуру по папкам? или по классам?

Comment: pom.xml покажи. Идея запускает без сбоев?

Comment: @Tachkin pom.xml не создаю, так как собирает сама Intellij IDEA. Если в ней запускать проект, всё всегда работает.

Comment: есть ли какие-либо исключения? например, `IOException`?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Да. Именно оно и есть. Его обрабатываю public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

Comment: Т.е. не обрабатываешь исключение, а просто выкидываешь из стека? Интересное решение, но спорное.

Comment: Если его обработать try{} catch(IOExeption e){} То картинки перестают появляться даже если запускать через Idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените строку на вот это

```
MIm[1][1] = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/Распределитель.png"));
```

Убедитесь, что картинка находиться в директории resources в корне вашего jar файла.

Comment: Это было не совсем то, но благодаря вам  я пересмотрел все свои файлы, они у меня png. Один из файлов был с названием PNG. Intellij IDEA это допускает, а когда читаешь с Jre из jar. Возникала ошибка.

Comment: лучше начать пользоваться системой сборки

Comment: Собственно возникает вопрос какой лучше?

Comment: @RodGers это очень индивидуально. Попробуйте несколько. Или возьмите тот который более популярен в вашем городе.