# maven assembly plugin и файл конфигурации spring

Tags: java, spring, maven

Созданный jar не находит файл конфигурации

pom

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>Main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

В майне

```
      ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите как вы загружаете конфигурацию

Comment: @MikhailVaysman  ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

Comment: это надо добавить в вопрос, а не в комментарий

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Свёртывание в Jar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642605/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-jar)